# Distinct and substri in android with sqlite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, contacts

I want get the first letter for all contacts without repetition i can't use something like this:

> Cursor flc = this.cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
>                   Proyection2, null, null, "UPPER("+ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+")");

Because Content providers don't allow functions in proyection with code this is explanation that i want:

> "Select distinct substr(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME+",
>   1, 1) from "+ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI "

I search a method for do this with content providers or accesing directly to bd but i don't know how.

Comment: That is probably not going to work. A `ContentProvider` is not a direct SQLite interface, it just looks similar and is often backed by an SQLite database. But there is no guarantee that a provider will allow / understand SQLite syntax in any way. The Contacts provider is one of those that has restrictions in place. Besides, the `UPPER(...)` part would go into the Projection parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Content providers are not a generic SQL interface; they support only those accesses that they have implemented, and they might not be based on an SQL database in the first place.

If you want to do any filtering or grouping not directly supported by a content provider, you have to do it yourself.